# SBT Native Packager Plugin Docker Error

Tags: docker, sbt

I have used the sbt docker plugin for one of my project and I get the following error when I ran:

```
sbt docker:publishLocal

Joes-MacBook-Pro:my-projects joe$ sbt docker:publishLocal
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=724M; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/joe/projects/my-projects/proj1/project
[info] Set current project to sally (in build file:/Users/joe/projects/my-projects/proj1/)
[info] Wrote /Users/joe/projects/my-projects/proj1/target/scala-2.11/sally_2.11-2.1.pom
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker" (in directory "/Users/joe/projects/my-projects/proj1/target/docker/docker/stage"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at sbt.SimpleProcessBuilder.run(ProcessImpl.scala:349)
    at sbt.AbstractProcessBuilder.run(ProcessImpl.scala:128)
    at sbt.AbstractProcessBuilder$$anonfun$runBuffered$1.apply(ProcessImpl.scala:159)
    at sbt.AbstractProcessBuilder$$anonfun$runBuffered$1.apply(ProcessImpl.scala:159)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$$anon$1.buffer(DockerPlugin.scala:275)
    at sbt.AbstractProcessBuilder.runBuffered(ProcessImpl.scala:159)
    at sbt.AbstractProcessBuilder.$bang(ProcessImpl.scala:156)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$.publishLocalDocker(DockerPlugin.scala:285)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$$anonfun$projectSettings$14.apply(DockerPlugin.scala:106)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$$anonfun$projectSettings$14.apply(DockerPlugin.scala:105)
    at scala.Function4$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function4.scala:35)
    at scala.Function4$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function4.scala:34)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    at sbt.SimpleProcessBuilder.run(ProcessImpl.scala:349)
    at sbt.AbstractProcessBuilder.run(ProcessImpl.scala:128)
    at sbt.AbstractProcessBuilder$$anonfun$runBuffered$1.apply(ProcessImpl.scala:159)
    at sbt.AbstractProcessBuilder$$anonfun$runBuffered$1.apply(ProcessImpl.scala:159)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$$anon$1.buffer(DockerPlugin.scala:275)
    at sbt.AbstractProcessBuilder.runBuffered(ProcessImpl.scala:159)
    at sbt.AbstractProcessBuilder.$bang(ProcessImpl.scala:156)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$.publishLocalDocker(DockerPlugin.scala:285)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$$anonfun$projectSettings$14.apply(DockerPlugin.scala:106)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$$anonfun$projectSettings$14.apply(DockerPlugin.scala:105)
    at scala.Function4$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function4.scala:35)
    at scala.Function4$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function4.scala:34)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (docker:publishLocal) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker" (in directory "/Users/joe/projects/my-projects/proj1/target/docker/docker/stage"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if docker is running? Try restarting the docker daemon. That should do the trick! Alternatively try setting the docker environment in every command line shell:

```
eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

where default is the name of the docker machine that you created. Make sure to replace with the one that you created.

Next, try giving the current user docker previliges:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```